# C/C++ return from x86 code

Tags: c++, assembly, return

I am currently working on using some ASM in C/C++

I have the following

```
__declspec(naked) unsigned long 
someFunction( unsigned long inputDWord )
{
    __asm
    {
    }
}
```

how, in asm, would I return the unsigned long?

Do I need to push something onto the stack and then call ret?
I haven't used Asm in a long time, and never inside C++ before.

Thanks!

Comment: The answer to this really depends on the architecture you're developing against.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to handle the function call yourself? Can't you just have local assembly inside the function? Or even better, use compiler intrinsics rather than assembly?

Comment: The easiest way to get the answer for the appropriate architecture and ABI is simply to compile a regular function and then look at the resulting asm.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Matteo Italia, I've corrected the usage of `ret`.

Put the retval in `eax` register, this is according to `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` conventions.

Then, depending on the calling convention, you should use the appropriate variant of `ret` instruction:

- In case of `__cdecl` convention (or similar) - use `ret`. On machine level this means `pop`-ing the return address from the stack and `jmp` to it. The caller is responsible for removing all the function parameters from the stack.
- In case of `__stdcall` convention (or similar) - use `ret X`, whereas `X` is the size of all the function arguments.

Comment: "whereas X is the size of all the arguments" - only if it's `__stdcall`, in `__cdecl` (usually the default) the cleanup is up to the caller, so it's plain `ret` (unless I'm forgetting something about `naked`).

Comment: @Matteo Italia: Oh, you're 100% right. Sorry, I just forgot this. I'll fix my post.